# Script to scale all images in word document to 100%

Tags: vba, ms-word

I get word 2010 documents containing images. Now for some reason these images are scaled to 133%.

Now I'm looking for a way to iterate through all images in the document and scale them to 100%. I found this script, but it does not work (and I got no clue about word macros, so I don't know why):

```
Sub AllGraphicsTo100() 

  Dim ILS As Word.InlineShape 
  Dim SHP As Word.Shape 

  For Each ILS In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes 
    If ILS.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then 
        ILS.ScaleHeight = 100 
        ILS.ScaleWidth = 100 
    End If 
  Next ILS 

  For Each SHP In ActiveDocument.Shapes 
    If SHP.Type = msoPicture Then 
        SHP.ScaleHeight 1#, True 
        SHP.ScaleWidth 1, True 
    End If 
  Next SHP 

End Sub
```

Additionally if the images are wider than the column I'd like to scale them to fit the width of the column instead of 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that your images are linked, rather than embedded. You can modify the macro to include linked images as well like this:

```
    Sub AllGraphicsTo100()

      Dim ILS As Word.InlineShape
      Dim SHP As Word.Shape

      For Each ILS In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If ILS.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Or ILS.Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture Then
            ILS.ScaleHeight = 100
            ILS.ScaleWidth = 100
        End If
      Next ILS

      For Each SHP In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If SHP.Type = msoPicture Or SHP.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
            SHP.ScaleHeight 1#, True
            SHP.ScaleWidth 1, True
        End If
      Next SHP

    End Sub
```

Comment: I have a similar problem and can't get this macro to work for me. Would the fact that the docs are opening in compatibility mode make a difference or the fact that they were converted from html originally?  I am able to reset pictures if I manually select them and use the Reset Picture toolbar button which if I record it, shows that it is using Selection.InlineShapes(1).Reset, but I've also been unable to get .reset to work from a macro. Do you need to do something special to force it to select the images?